# Clarification of what should I do in this Laurent series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

For $z \in \mathbb{C}$, I am asked to expand $$
\frac{1}{z-2}-\frac{1}{z-3}
$$ into Laurent series around $z_0 =2$.  I know how to handle the right term, but how about the left one? should I expand it too? and if so how? It is not clear to me what the final answer should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* expand it, since it is already of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-2)^n$; you simply take$$a_n=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }n=-1\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: ohhhhh how silly from my self, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.